Who are the 12 apostles of the Lamb?
Introduction: Every person who believes in Jesus is called his disciple, but not every disciple is an apostle. An apostle means “one who is sent out”.
John 17:3 informs us that the Father sent the Son. Hebrews 3:1-2 declares that Jesus was sent out by the Father, and he is “the apostle and high priest whom we confess.  He was faithful to the one who appointed him.”
Furthermore, “Christ is faithful as a Son over God’s house – and we are his house” (Hebrews 3:6).
After the resurrection of Christ Jesus his followers “continued steadfastly to the apostles’ doctrine” (Acts 2:42) which is the gospel of Christ.
We know that the Holy Spirit sent out Barnabas and Saul (Acts 13:2-4) and that Ananias was sent by the Lord Jesus to anoint Saul. After Ananias placed his hands on Saul, he was filled with the Holy Spirit. Then Saul was baptised, and he went forth as the apostle to the Gentiles.
Later the apostle John had a vision of the holy city which is surrounded by a wall. The name of the wall is Salvation (Isaiah 60:18). There are 12 gates in the four walls and they have the names of the 12 tribes of the children of Israel, the children of promise. 12 foundations support the structure above (the wall and the gates). The apostolic foundation of the holy city is based on the gospel and doctrine of Christ, which is “the power of God unto salvation” (Romans 1:16). The wall of the city has twelve foundations, and on them were the names of the twelve apostles of the Lamb.
Question: What biblical evidence is there as to who the apostles of the Lamb are?

There were twelve, then one betrayed and there were eleven. Two attempts were made to re-instate a twelfth, one attempt by gambling and the other by promoting a natural relative. Both attempts failed as can be seen in Acts by the first never being mentioned again and by the second causing a problem regarding legality. The one who stands out as the 'chosen vessel' and the one who corrects said legality . . . . .  is the obvious twelfth as chosen and sent by Jesus Christ. I don't see a problem, myself, to affirming 12 apostles as a title.. True, others functioned apostolically.

From a previous answer, we know the early church viewed the 12 apostles of the Lamb as those defined in Acts 1:15-22.  By the well-adopted, historically approved process, by lot, Matthias was chosen.  These are the 12.
Think of Joshua 4.  12 stones from the Jordan being the foundation, the remembrance of deliverance v7.  There were many who crossed the Jordan.  There were 150 people in the Upper Room.  They could have picked any number of people, but they fulfilled prophecy of the 12.
The foundations do not have a "precedence".  None would assert themselves in that manner.  Which tribe is superior to the others?  Which apostle would claim superiority over the others (we know what man did)?
The word apostle means one who is sent, a delegate.  The 12 were there from baptism to ascension, eyewitnesses, sent.  Subsequently, Paul was chosen to go to the nations (Gentiles), doing what the 12 had also been commissioned to do (Matthew 28).

The twelve disciples chosen by the Lord for special training were so called, Luk 6:13; 9:10. Paul, though he had seen the Lord Jesus, 1Cr 9:1; 15:8, had not 'companied with' the Twelve 'all the time' of His earthly ministry, and hence was not eligible for a place among them, according to Peter's description of the necessary qualifications, Act 1:22. Paul was commissioned directly, by the Lord Himself, after His Ascension, to carry the Gospel to the Gentiles. Vines Expository Dictionary of New Testament Words (apostle)

The 12, Paul, Barnabas, Andronicus, Junias, Silas, Timothy, and others (Phil 2:25) are apostles.  There are many apostles, just as there were many in the Upper Room or who crossed the Jordan, but only some fulfilled the prophecy of the 12.

OP Are we to understand that Revelation 21:14 is saying there were literally only 12 apostles of the Lamb?

12 apostles of the foundations, though others later became apostles.

Revelation 21:14 is saying that the 12 names specified in the vision are those of the apostles at Christ's time. Anything more/less seems speculative.

The wall of the city had twelve foundations, and on them were the names of the twelve apostles of the Lamb.

The original 12 it most likely refers to: Peter, John, James, Andrew, Philip, Thomas, Bartholomew, Matthew, James son of Alpheus, Simon, Judas son of James and Matthias (Acts 1:12–14; 1:26)
The apostles were key witnesses and leaders in the early Church, their names being on the foundations of the New Jerusalem signifies their eternal importance and the enduring nature of their testimonies
